# Find the curvatures intrinsic, mean and extrinsic of a half-plan in hyperbolic metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, hyperbolic-geometry, curvature

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

> Let $\mathbb{H}^3=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: z>0\}$ with a hyperbolic metric $g_{ij} = \dfrac{\delta_{ij}}{z^2}$. Use the mobile referential method to find the curvatures (intrinsic, mean and extrinsic) of a open half-plan whose boundary it's in the plan $\{z=0\}$ and whose normal (pointing up) forms an angle $\theta$ with a vertical direction (pointing up).

Well, I used the referential:
$$\begin{cases} 
t_1= z(1,0,0) \\
t_2 = z(0,-\cos(\theta), \sin (\theta)) \\
t_3 = z(0, \sin (\theta), \cos (\theta)) \end{cases}$$

And I get:

$$ w_1=\dfrac{dx}{z}, \quad w_2= -\dfrac{\cos(\theta)}{z}dy+\dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{z}dz,$$
$$ w_3= \dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{z}dy+\dfrac{\cos(\theta)}{z}dz, \quad w_{12} = \dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{z}dx$$

But when I do $dw_{12} = -k w_1 \wedge w_2$ it doesn't work

PS: $w_1 \wedge w_2$ denotes the exterior product.

Comment: Why are you not writing \wedge for wedge product? Please show your work for arriving at $\omega_{12}$.

Comment: Also, check signs on $\omega_2$ and $\omega_3$.

Comment: P.S. Your formula for $\omega_{12}$ is correct. What are $\omega_{13}$ and $\omega_{23}$ and why do you think you’re wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I achieved solve this exercise.

Comment: PS: I didn't know this command "$\wedge$"

Comment: Cool. I've actually never seen this example. It's a nice one, and a good way to check instrinsic curvature computation with the Gauss equation in $\Bbb H^3$.